# Drupal 7 node_add() pass parameters

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

```
<?php 
   module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
   $node_form = node_add('post');
   print drupal_render($node_form);
?>
```

This is my code snippet. 
The problem is, that I want to pass several parameters for pre-selected default values:

/node/add/post?field_type=3&field_post_id=122

Like the example above.

How can I add parameters (such as "field_type=3" & "field_post_id=122") to my PHP code example above?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use node_add here, there are several ways to do that (as usual):

1. Have a look at the [prepopulate](https://www.drupal.org/project/prepopulate) module
2. If the module does not fit, alter the node form by using hook_form_FORMID_alter as [described in the API.](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like McGo's answer (which is good) for some reason, here's an example of how to do that:

```
$node_form = node_add('post');
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
    // this query string is a field prepop.
    if (strpos($key, 'field_') === 0) { // === to prevent a false negative.
        // this field exists on the form
        if (!empty($node_form[$key])) {
            $node_form[$key]['#default_value'] = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

While untested, something like this should work.